# Geoserver Vector tiles hollow issue with layer

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles, multi-polygon

I am using vector tiles from PostGIS, Geoserver for the world layer,
I have multiple layers for the global level,
I have seen multiple holes and missing tiles of some boundaries in the layer of vector tiles.

I have tried multiple methods to resolve the issue still not found the solution.

1. geometry st_isvalid,
2. geometry topology.

WMS layer with the same geometry.
no hollow.

[image]

same layer for vector tiles hole in Layer

[image]

Is this related to the multiPolygons/geometryCollection issue or something else?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what exactly you see with an image, what methods you have tried and how they have not helped.

Comment: you say "I have tried multiple methods to resolve the issue still not found the solution." - what are they? Also what are you using to render the vector tiles?

Answer (score 0):

Geometry must be valid use `st_simplifypreservetopology` and ensure that you have all valid geometries (>=4 vertices).